# Print multiple ranges to PDF : VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:I","K:Q").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF
```

This prints the two ranges adjacent to each other.
Is there anyway I can print the two ranges on top of each other?

Comment: I would suggest using a dummy sheet and then remove it when you're done.